# Feed could not be found at link. Why so?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I want to display RSS posts in WordPress. The default RSS plugin lets one see items by adding source. I added [valid RSS source](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Ffeed%2F%40mbertulli), but WordPress gives following error,

```
RSS Error: A feed could not be found at https://medium.com/feed/@mbertulli. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed.
```

Comment: are you using plugin??which version of wp you have?

Comment: I have the latest version (4.7). The RSS plugin is a default WordPress widget.

Comment: can you change a theme and check??

Comment: I am using the default new 2017 WordPress theme. www.fahaduddin.com/mattbertulli

Comment: I mean to say got for lower version

Comment: go for default theme